# Remove Duplicates from Echoing in PHP Foreach

Tags: php, html, foreach

I'm trying to use get the response headers using PHP.

Here's my current code:

```
foreach ($headers as $name => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $key => $moreinfo) {
    echo "$name === $moreinfo \n";
  }
}
```

I basically just don't want there to be multiple `$name` entries.

For example, I'm currently seeing this being echoed:

```
date === Sun, 03 Nov 2019 03:03:11 GMT 
date === Sun, 03 Nov 2019 03:03:11 GMT 
via === 1.1 varnish 
via === 1.1 varnish 
connection === keep-alive 
x-served-by === cache-bur17530-BUR 
x-served-by === cache-bur17548-BUR
```

I would want it changed to just showing this:

```
date === Sun, 03 Nov 2019 03:03:11 GMT 
via === 1.1 varnish 
connection === keep-alive 
x-served-by === cache-bur17548-BUR
```

Is there anything that could just be modified in the `foreach` to make this happen?

Comment: What is your expected output from the data you posted on pastebin?

Comment: Can you share the input data, such that others can reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all fields of id zero (fixed):

```
foreach ($headers as $name => $value) {
    echo "{$name} === {$headers[$name][0]} \n"; // or $value[0]
}
```

Adding a simple `break` will output one name field max by ending the loop after one go.

```
foreach ($headers as $name => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $key => $moreinfo) {
    echo "$name === $moreinfo \n";
    break;
  }
}
```

You can keep a list of what you've shown already and check it.

Comment: Fixed variable in first example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php inbuilt array method called 
array_unique(), which takes two parameters, one is the array you want to filter unique vales, next parameter is sorting option.
Check the documentation for more usage [php array unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: I don't think that will work because I'm trying to echo unique values depending upon the array's ID, not the content.  Can you post sample code of how you think it would work with my code?

Comment: You can first filter out the unique values and then echo in any format you want.

Comment: Here's a copy of the array:  https://pastebin.com/raw/4GAsMzMt - like I said earlier, the array is multi-dimensional and has I want to remove duplicates based upon the ID, not the content.  For example, `x-request-guid` shouldn't have 2 values, it should just have `556b1a00-56a5-4253-b682-76541d788c14`.  If you know how to make `array_unique` work with IDs instead of the content, please post an example.

Comment: @Stacker Could you post an example of expected output? `x-request-guid` has 2 values, why would you not want to print them separately?

Comment: @Stacker Also, please do a `var_export(your_array_variable)` while sharing.